# How do I create a project tree from yasnippet

Tags: yasnippet, project, template

I have built a project prototype as a module in a directory tree in the following example:

```
module
  main.ext
  module_feature
     item.ext
     another_item.ext
```

I would like to insert the module into another project using elisp while dynamically renaming part of the directory or file structure and also part of the file content. i.e project name, author etc...

What I did was to manually create all the contents of the project structure into snippets using yasnippet which I will later insert into the next project using `yas-insert-snippet` I
also use elisp to manually create the directory structure of the module.

This practice is a bit tedious and error proof.
In case of constant modification on the module source, I have to replicate all the changes in the created snippets.

What handy alternative do you suggest?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Have you considered using a template with something like Cookiecutter: https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/2.0.2/

Comment: Since I'm working in emacs, I prefer to stick to it.